# WPF ListBox sometimes ignoring SelectedItem change

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, binding, listbox

I have list box with next properties:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
x:Name="listBox"
ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
```

In code i have one static model and it can be used in few windows.

Only one window can be displayed at the same time.

Everything is working without any problems if UI already loaded. 
But when window is just ready to be loaded i set SelectedItem does nothing (first item is selected)

When i set brakepoint i noticed SelectedItem called from view with NULL or first item. (StackTrace doesnot contains my code)

I tryed to set selected item before view loaded and after:

```
model.SelectedItem=first;

view.Loaded += (o, e) => 
{
    model.SelectedItem=first; 
}
```

And still i have same problem.

Comment: And if you're trying to execute e.g. via command it works? I know that's not the desired implementation but I think that you're calling it to early, so that the `Items` are null.

Comment: Looks like changing order of properties solved the problem...

Comment: Can you give me some details? I'm also interested in the solution.

Comment: I just set ItemsSource before SelectedItem and now its works. Looks like its trying to SelectedItem before ItemsSource is set.

Comment: Ah yes I remember. I think it's the same like create bindings on a `ComboBox`. Pretty odd behavior of WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сhanging order of properties solved the problem.
Bind ItemsSourcefirst and then SelectedItem.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Xaml DataBinding is evaluated during the loading of the window.
So it is normal that `SelectedItem` is null within `SelectionChanged` event if it's fired before `Window.Loaded` occurred.

You can verify this by checking if your listbox has items before the window is fully loaded.